# Why does the command "wait sleep" not work although the function was marked as "async"?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following function:

```js
async function updateData() {
  return firebase.database().ref(varurl3).child('UserCount/count').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    var username = snapshot.val();
    var username2 = username + 1;
    return firebase.database().ref(varurl3).child('Users').child(username2).child('User').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      var username3 = snapshot.val();
      if (username3 != null) {
        await Sleep(3000);
      }
    });
  });
}
timeupdater = setInterval(updateData, 100);
```

I have marked my function as "async" but the following error message still appears:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async generators". Can anyone tell me how I can solve this problem?
I would appreciate a helpful answer.

Comment: Only your outermost `updateData` function is marked `async`. You need to make the innermost `function(snapshot) { ... }` async in order to use `await` within it

Comment: `then` is another function

Comment: using `.then` inside an `async` function is usually bad code - I wouldn't say never use it (I've seen one example where it's the easiest solution to a problem) but, in this case, it's not

Comment: Also, it may not be obvious, but `updateData` **will** be called every 100ms, and the sleep does nothing anyway